# How to access div ids using xpath?[selenium webdriver]

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<div class="logo">..................</div> </div>
```

logo is inner div.

I need to acces col-lg-3 col... div content using xpath.

I did this in java:
WebElement mydiv = driver.findElement(By.className("col-lg-3 ")) ;
but it does not work - because it has spaces in the name.

How do I access this using xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, you could access it like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".col-lg-3 .logo"));
```

Since you asked, in XPath, it could be:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'col-lg-3')]/div[contains(@class, 'logo')]")
```

As you can see, the CSS selector is much simpler.

Comment: sorry my first div class name is this: col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6, it has spaces already! selecting with css does not work

Comment: the `.` selector in CSS doesn't care about spaces.  you can take a look at [this blog post](http://ddavison.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html) which would explain a little bit better on how CSS can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To see xpath, I suggest to install Firebug and FirePath; those extensions are Firefox.

Example:
Can you see the image? [xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afnMZ.png)

Imagine that you don't have **id** neither **name** locators or you need to use **xpath**

1. Open Firefox.
2. Click on "Firebug". (#1)
3. There a panel.
4. Click on "Click an element in the page to inspect" icon (#2)
5. Click on "FirePath" tab. (#3)
6. Select the element that you wish (#4)
7. It displays the xpath into textbox. (#5)

So, you need to add this line:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/fieldset/p[1]/input"));
```